# Remove seconds in Chrome input=time

Tags: google-chrome, time, input, webkit

In the last update of Chrome ("23.0.1271.64 m" in my case), it seems that input=time now includes seconds that are inactive and not clickable. This doesn't look nice in our site so I want to know if someone have found a way to remove seconds.
Unfortunately jsfiddle is down and I can't post an example there, but I post it here so people can read it anyway.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input type="time" value="00:44" name="tiiiiden"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Since seconds is only "lying there" and are not editable, it's possible that this is a bug and it will be fixed pretty soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome 23 stable on OSX and Linux omits the seconds fields if it is unnecessary, and Chrome 24 beta on Windows also omits it.  I recommend you to wait for Chrome 24 stable release.

Answer (score 28):

I know this is a very old question, but I just found the solution.

You must change your step to 60. If you leave your step default (1), it will have to increase one second, so it must show seconds at the field.

If you set your step to 60, it will increase 1 minute at a time, so it doesn't need to show the seconds.

Comment: doesn't seem to work on Android 4.4 / Chrome 30 webview / US locale

Comment: It seems this is [a bug in Android Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28664821/245966) which was solved in Chrome 43

Comment: It will also show seconds even with `step` set to 60 if the `min` or `max` contain seconds.

Answer (score 7):

@hend's solution of setting `step` to 60 works on an empty input, but if you load your form with values prepopulated, you'll find that seconds may reappear in a disabled state.

[image]

You can mask them and the dangling colon with the following CSS:

```
  ::-webkit-datetime-edit-second-field {
    background: $color-white;
    color: transparent;
    margin-left: -3px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
```

Which yields the following:

[image]

Comment: dangling colon is there in chrome

Comment: Chrome has been updated many times since this answer.  Your final style block may differ based on your particular use case. This example is just a starting point.

Comment: How to hide that colon?

Comment: This will hide the seconds - but if you click on the clock icon then you get the 3 numbers (h, m, s) still prompted

Answer (score 4):

I could not find any change/release notes for `23.0.1271.64 m` that relates to any changes of the `form` `input` types but according to the latest working draft of the [HTML5 markup documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/) by W3C the `input type="time"` element does not support any other time format than "*a valid partial-time as defined in [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)*", and that is `hh:mm:ss.ff` and `hh:mm:ss`.

As there are no attribute to specify your own date/time format on neither one of the date/time `input` [elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/elements.html#elements) you are stuck with the defined format(s).

From [input type=time – time input control](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.time.html#input.time)

> **Value**: A valid partial-time as defined in [[RFC 3339]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).
> **Examples:**
> 23:20:50.52
> 17:39:57

From [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)

> time-secfrac    = "." 1*DIGIT
> partial-time    = time-hour ":" time-minute ":" time-second [time-secfrac]

Finally, I am including a screenshot of how `Chrome 23.0.1271.64 m` renders the different time formats (on my machine);

```
<input type="time" value="23:20:50.52" />
<input type="time" value="17:39:57" />
<input type="time" value="13:37" />
<input type="time" value="" />
```

[image]

The markup is also available at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/ZGTUr/).

Comment: There seems to be a bug in Chrome that prevents time fields from being submitted if they have seconds (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGTUr/12/)).

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem. I used a fixed width with `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden` to hide the seconds, but when the input is focused the problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, if you are using a pre populated date to fill your input, just use this :

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setSeconds(0);
myDate.setMilliseconds(0);
```

With the input tag like this:

```
<input type="datetime-local" step="60"/>
```

I personaly use angular but anything should work since Date is Javascript.

Comment: In shorter you can do ```myDate.setSeconds(0,0);```

Answer (score 1):

Android Chrome and Webbrowser still have that problem, so I made a smartphone-specific work-around using angularjs:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rvjuf/12/

How it works:

There are 2 elements that handle this:

```
<span>{{ timeDisplay }}</span>
<input type="time" ng-model="time">
```

In the link code, style the elements (can do that in CSS file as well), and bind to the click even of the span:

```
        scope.inputElement.css({
            position: "absolute",
            "z-index": "-10000",
            opacity: 0
        });
        scope.displayElement.css({
            width: "200px",
            height: "20px",
            background: "blue",
            color: "white",
        });
        scope.displayElement.bind("click", function(event) {
            scope.inputElement[0].focus();
            scope.inputElement[0].click();
        });
```

Then, register a change listener for the time value and update the timeDisplay variable:

```
        $scope.$watch('time', function(nv, ov) {
            var parts = nv.split(" ")[0].split(":");
            var hours = parts[0];
            var minutes = parts[1];
            $scope.timeDisplay = $filter('date')(new Date(2014, 03, 06, hours, minutes, 0), "H:mm");
        });
```

So, when the user taps on the span, the input either gets focussed or clicked (iOS and ANDROID make some difference there), causing the native time picker UI to come up.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **pattern attribute** on your time input.

```
<input 
    type="time" 
    name="time"
    pattern="[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Mac and `step="60"` still does not work, it could be your time preferences.

Chrome was using the "Short" time. I removed the seconds and milliseconds from the Short time, restarted Chrome and that solved it for me.

Found in: Language & Region > Advanced... > Times

[image: Time & Date - Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

We're using moment.js to fix this. You can round down the seconds to avoid the milis in a prePopulated input time by setting on controller with:

```
const localDate = moment(data.date).startOf('minute').toDate();
```

I hope it helps ;)