# How to remove seconds of HTML5 input type time

Tags: android, css, html, google-chrome

I'm developing HTML5 app for both Android and IOS and encountering some sort of buggy issue.
What I want to achieve is to get `HH:MM` format of `<input type="time">`

According to W3C
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#time-state-(type=time)

Default attribute of `step` is 60s. This means users would never be able to select seconds without any extra attributes and The timepickers of both IOS safari(IOS7/8) and Android(jellybeans - lolipop chrome latest) works as they are expected.

The problem is that Chrome's `input` displays `HH:MM:SS` instead of `HH:MM`. even though `SS` never get any value but `00`

Is there any way to remove `SS` part?

**Edit**
This issue is only on Android's Chrome.

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yymvLk9a/

thanks in advance

Comment: The title and the first paragraph says "input date," but this is about <input type=time>, right?  Does "placeholder" means the value set by a user, not HTML 'placeholder' attribute?

Comment: Is this for Google Chrome on Android, not on desktop, right?

Comment: @int32_t how you recognized is perfectly correct.question updated.and Yes it's Chrome on Android.

Comment: AFAIK, we have no way to hide the seconds. However, desktop Chrome doesn't show the seconds field if it's unnecessary.  So, this should be a bug, and I recommend you to file a bug in crbug.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution for this.

html

```
<input id="foo" />
```

js

```
$("#foo").on("change",function(){
  $(this).attr("type","text");
});
$("#foo").on("touchstart",function(){
  $(this).attr("type","time");
});
```

display the value as `type="text"` and change the type before keyboard shows up.

simple but works great for me.

**EDITED**

I reported this bug to google.and got confirmed and fixed.
This bug will be disappeared next update.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459966

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug and linking it here! Solved in Chrome 43

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the time from MySQL you can use

```
$sql = "SELECT *, TIME_FORMAT(PickupTime, '%H:%i') AS PT FROM Trips WHERE TripID=".$tid;
```

then when filling the form

```
type="time" id="pickuptime" name="pickuptime" value="<?php echo $row['PT']; ?>"
```

This seems to present in Firefox as HH:mm without seconds